# EWS: Mailbox address from a Calendar FolderId, is it possible?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have stored Calendar FolderIds in order report on calendar events which a user has access to. I'm using Exchange Web Services via c# (`using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices`)

These calendars can be associated with the authenticated user's mailbox, a shared mailbox, an impersonated|delegated mailbox, or a public mailbox. And now I'd like to go from the FolderId to the mailbox address.

Ideally there'd be a function to

```
string address = getMailboxAddress(new FolderId("AAJk...AA="));
```

Comment: What is a mailbox address?

Comment: Exchange has a Mailbox object. I want the smtp address ("example@example.com") from `Mailbox.Address.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the FolderId what you have is the EWS version of this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee217297(v=exchg.80).aspx which means with the data you have doesn't contain the Email Address. You would be better at the time you store the CalendarId store the Email address its associated with.

You can try using ConvertId with a generic non resolvable email Address this should return the EmailAddress the folder belongs (won't work for Public Folder) to eg

```
     AlternateId aiAlternateid = new AlternateId(IdFormat.EwsId, SharedFoder.Id.UniqueId, "mailbox@domain.com");
    AlternateIdBase aiResponse = service.ConvertId(aiAlternateid, IdFormat.EwsId);
    Console.WriteLine(((AlternateId)aiResponse).Mailbox);
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks. Can't the Provider UID portion of the FolderId get me to the calendar owner and the email address?

Comment: No for a Mailbox the UID in the Folder Id would be the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815641.aspx. You maybe able to extract the MailboxGUID from the ewsId (but that format isn't documented AFAIK).